# Connect: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking

I'm new to unix network programming and I have tried to write a program to connect to Google's server. However, I got a error while using the connect() function. (OS: OS X)

**Connect error: Socket operation on non-socket**

I have worked at it for 4 hours but I could not find out the problem. Here is my code:

```
#define SERVPORT 80

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, sockfd;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  if ( (host = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
    printf("gethostbyname error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i = 0; host->h_addr_list[i]; i++) {
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)) {
    printf("socket error\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr = *( (struct in_addr *)host->h_addr_list[i]);
    const char *ip = inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr);
    printf("connect to %s\n", ip);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
      printf("connect error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
    }

 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `socklen_t` value for `connect` should be `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)`.

Comment: You have broken assignment-inside-if. A debugger would show you that in about 45 seconds. Fix parentheses or, better, move the assignment out of `if`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I see the problem.  It's this line:

```
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1))
```

The == operator has precedence over the = operator.  Look at the way you have the parentheses structured on that expression a bit more carefully to see what I mean.  sockfd is getting initialize to "0" as a result of being assigned a boolean expression (socket(...) == -1).

Change the socket initialization to this:

```
  for (i = 0; host->h_addr_list[i]; i++) 
  {

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
    {
        printf("socket error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Or if you prefer the "assign and compare" on the same line approach, you can probably say this:

```
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
```

Notice the subtle difference.

Comment: I have tested the socked value and wondered why it was always zero. Thank you !!

Comment: If you're using gcc, this is yet *another* reason to turn on `-Wall`, which would give you "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"

Comment: @Nmzzz - this is the exact reason that I disallow comparing the result of a function with a variable assignment in the same statement on my team. It's less readable and it makes me have to look up this stuff in the C precedence table when I do code reviews.

Comment: Don't you think it's time you knew the operator precedence off by heart?

Comment: @EJP - I keep a copy of the operator precedence table on a 3x5 card hidden up my sleeve while at work. On the other side of that same card are all the command line parameters for "ls" and the listing to "HelloWorld.c". I'm always forgetting if it's argc or argv as the first parameter to main. :)

Comment: Thank goodness for SO. My first week of socket and message queue programming and every problem so far has been identified here, including this semantic problem. Wow!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, thanks for reminding me to insert -Wall in my return to C after 30 years away from it. It found several more problems before I did.

Comment: @selbie I keep my K&R (first edition) to hand. The precedence table is on page 49. :) Full bracketing is safest, and makes a vi "%" work well, especially d% to kill a term of the expression.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you!